# C# Json consume out putting null values Asp.net core blazor

Tags: c#, json, rest, asp.net-core

I have a web api that returns an array of type of object. Web api is working fine. When i attempt to deserialize the object into array of type object I only get null values. What am I missing?

Json:

```
{
    "results":"[{\"Name\":\"Rocky\",\"Breed\":\"Pitbull\",\"Color\":\"Brown\",\"Weight\":\"76\",\"OwnerUserId\":null,\"FamilyId\":\"1006949\"},{\"Name\":\"Casper\",\"Breed\":\"Terrier \",\"Color\":\"White \",\"Weight\":\"15\",\"OwnerUserId\":null,\"FamilyId\":\"1006949\"}]"
}
```

deserialize code:

```
public async Task values()
{
    var AJson = new root();
    var client = http.CreateClient();
    var response = await client.GetAsync("https://doggoapi2020.azurewebsites.net/Doggies/1006949");
    var responsebody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
        
    AJson = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<root>(responsebody);
}
```

Model:

```
public class DoggoData
{
     
    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Breed")]
    public string Breed { get; set; }
     
    public string Color { get; set; }
     
    public string Weight { get; set; }
      
    public string OwnerUserId { get; set; }
   
    public string FamilyId { get; set; }

}

public class root
{
    public DoggoData[] Jsonres { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: I believe [JSON arrays](https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_json_arrays.asp) should be without quotation marks, [in your case](https://jsonblob.com/4b290862-cad0-11ea-98f5-e38063b5bf54)

Comment: I used newton serializer to serialize the data...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Change your root class to this. Json properties have to match the names

```
public class Root
{
    [JsonProperty("results")]
    public string Jsonres { get; set; }
}
```

Your results has a string and once you get that string, you can deserialize that to the List of DoggoData.

```
public class DoggoData
{

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Name")]
    public string Name { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty(PropertyName = "Breed")]
    public string Breed { get; set; }

    public string Color { get; set; }

    public string Weight { get; set; }

    public string OwnerUserId { get; set; }

    public string FamilyId { get; set; }

}

public class Root
{
    [JsonProperty("results")]
    public string Jsonres { get; set; }
}

Root obj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Root>(json);
List<DoggoData> listObj = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<DoggoData>>(obj.Jsonres);

// Or
List<DoggoData> listObj2 = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<List<DoggoData>>(JObject.Parse(json)["results"]);
```

Naming convention for the class name is with Uppercase first letter. I would recommend using `Root` instead of `root`.

Comment: Thank you! You're answer worked out great and gave me great insight! I upvoted your answer but my account is new so it won't show.

Comment: If this or any answer has solved your question please consider [accepting it](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/5234/179419) by clicking the check-mark. This indicates to the wider community that you've found a solution and gives some reputation to both the answerer and yourself. There is no obligation to do this.